# Segmentation fault with dynamic array of lists

Tags: c, arrays, list, dynamic

```
typedef struct LabSection {
    StudentInfoT *head;
    int starting_hour;
    working_days day;
} LabSectionT;



typedef struct StudentInfo {
    char* name;
    int tmhma;
    struct StudentInfo* next;
} StudentInfoT;
```

I have these two structs and i want to create a dynamic array of labs using this function

```
LabSectionT* DataInsert (int *sections_number) {
    int students_number, max_lab_size;
    int how_many_sections;
    LabSectionT *labs_array;
    int i;
    char student_name[MAX_STUDENT_NAME_SIZE];
    char formatstring[13];
    sprintf(formatstring, "%%%ds",MAX_STUDENT_NAME_SIZE -1);
    int section,time,day;

    printf("Enter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &students_number);
    printf("Enter maximum lab size: ");
    scanf("%d", &max_lab_size);

    LabSectionT* labs_head = NULL;


    how_many_sections = students_number/max_lab_size; 
    labs_array = (LabSectionT*)malloc(how_many_sections * sizeof(LabSectionT));
    if (labs_array == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory for labs\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    labs_head = labs_array;

    for ( i = 0, time = 8, day = Mon; i < how_many_sections; i++,time++) {
        if (time > 21) {
            time = 8;
            day++;
        }

        if ((day >= Mon ) && (day <= Fri) && (time >= 8) && (time <= 21)) {
            labs_array[i].starting_hour = time;
            labs_array[i].day = day;
        }
    }
    if (debug == ON) {
        printf("\n>>Created %d sections<<\n", how_many_sections);
    }
    sections_number = &how_many_sections;

    for (i = 0; i < how_many_sections; i++) {
        labs_array[i].head = NULL; 
    }

    StudentInfoT* new_student;

    for (i = 0; i < students_number; i++) {
        new_student = NULL;
        printf("Enter student name: ");
        scanf(formatstring, student_name);
        new_student = (StudentInfoT*)malloc(sizeof(StudentInfoT));
        if (new_student == NULL){
            printf("Couldn't allocate memory for new student\n");
        }
        new_student->name=student_name;
        section = i % max_lab_size;
        InsertStudent(labs_array, new_student, section);



    }
    return(labs_head);

}
```

When there are more students than max_lab_size i create a new lab section
I'm getting segmentation faults when i'm trying to print the section using `PrintSections(sections_head, *sections_number)`;
Edit: The segmentation happens when I try to use the address of the array in print function

I think the problem is that the array will be **LabSectionT

Am I right?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger and examined the data?  You most likely have a null pointer somewhere.

Comment: You know unless `students_number` is a perfect multiple of `max_lab_size` you're going to get integer division roundoff, right? So 40 students in a lab size of 30 will be.. one, leaving 10 students literally out in the cold.

Comment: Without knowing what `sections_head` is, there's no way to be sure, but I'm guessing its the variable you're assigning the dynamic array to. In which case: No. Passing a pointer to a function means exactly that: the called function receives _the value of the variable_, which in case of a pointer is a memory address. However, your code is allocating memory left & right, but never freeing it. I also don't see the _point_ of the `labs_head` variable... Nor do I see the point in your passing a pointer to an int to your function...

Comment: Oh and as ever _don't cast the void * `malloc` returns_, and don't use _array_ and _pointer_ as though they mean the same thing: they _don't_. And to answer your question: _No_: passing a pointer, as ever, is passing the value of that variable. In case of a pointer, the value just happens to be an address in memory, to pass a pointer to a function that expects a pointer to a pointer, you have to pass `&some_ptr_var` the address of a pointer variable

Comment: When there are more students than max_lab_size i create a new lab section.
I pass pointer to int in function because i need this value to be changed by the function without returning it. Thanks for the pointer tip i had forgotten it.

Comment: One of the problem i can see is `new_student->name=student_name;`: `student_name` is local. So if you try to read the student name out of `DataInsert()`, a segmentation fault is likely to appear. Try to `malloc` some space for your string (`MAX_STUDENT_NAME_SIZE`...) and use `sprintf(new_student->name,"%s",student_name);` If `MAX_STUDENT_NAME_SIZE` is a macro, you may declare `char name[MAX_STUDENT_NAME_SIZE];` in `StudentInfo`